# Pulling NSDate from Core Data and displaying it IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am making an iPhone App and I have an NSDate in Core data and I am trying to display it but I keep getting this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81b7840'.

The code I have below is pulling the data from item which is a dictionary. How can I get this to work?

```
self.lblTheDate.text = [self.item valueForKey:@"MyDate"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something similar to the following to convert an NSDate (in your dictionary) into an NSString but select the correct date and time styles you require:

```
self.lblTheDate.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[self.item valueForKey:@"MyDate"] dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle]
```

There are various options for the date & time styles:

```
NSDateFormatterNoStyle     : Specifies no style,
NSDateFormatterShortStyle  : Specifies a short style, typically numeric only, such as “11/23/37” or “3:30pm”,
NSDateFormatterMediumStyle : Specifies a medium style, typically with abbreviated text, such as “Nov 23, 1937”,
NSDateFormatterLongStyle   : Specifies a long style, typically with full text, such as “November 23, 1937” or “3:30:32pm”,
NSDateFormatterFullStyle   : Specifies a full style with complete details, such as “Tuesday, April 12, 1952 AD” or “3:30:42pm PST”
```

Note that the format for these date and time styles is not exact because they depend on the locale, user preference settings and the operating system version.

Class Reference:
[NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you get a NSDate object and want to assign it to a text field that wants a NSString as argument.
you must first convert the date to a NSstring, for example using  NSDateFormat